# Multiple modules for multiple entry points in webpack config for reactjs app

Tags: reactjs, webpack

In case of multiple entry points, this is the example I got:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        user1: path.join(__dirname, './client/app1.js'),
        user2: path.join(__dirname, './client/app2.js'),
        user3: path.join(__dirname, './client/app3.js')
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, './static/bundle/'),
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    ...
}
```

But, I am confused about the term `entry`. Does it mean the entry url? What if user visits to root and then visits another page?

For example, suppose I have one site `example.com` and two other pages `example.com/register` and `example.com/contact`. Now I want to get common files for `example.com` and load only register module code in `example.com/register` and contact module code in `example.com/contact`. The entry point is same, `example.com`. Will above solution work in this scenario?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But, I am confused about the term entry. Does it mean the entry url?

No.  It is the entry for webpack to start bundling.  If you have multiple entries in your webpack config, then there will be multiple output bundles.  This is why you output uses a `[name].js` in the filename.

It is up to you to make sure the correct bundle(s) are available to any particular page that is loaded.

---

**Answering question in comment:**

If I understand what you are trying to do, I believe you can use [CommonsChunkPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/) to construct a common bundle and an entry for each page.

So your webpack config might look something like

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        index: path.join(__dirname, './src/index.js'),
        register: path.join(__dirname, './src/register.js'),
        contact: path.join(__dirname, './src/contact.js')
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, './static/bundle/'),
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new CommonsChunkPlugin("commons.js")
    ]
    ...
}
```

Then your index page would be something like

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        ...
        <script src="static/bundle/commons.js"></script>
        <script src="static/bundle/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the register page would be something like

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        ...
        <script src="static/bundle/commons.js"></script>
        <script src="static/bundle/register.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the contact page would be something like

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        ...
        <script src="static/bundle/commons.js"></script>
        <script src="static/bundle/contact.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How can I decide which entry I have? For example, in above case, I have described the scenarios for my site(example.com). Can you please explain in light of this site configuarion?

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Thanks for the insight. This is what I was looking for. One thing more, I am working on react right now. Being a SPA, react has only one index.html file. How can I ensure to load respective bundle in each case?

Comment: If you have a SPA (react doesn't HAVE to be a SPA), then having multiple entries in your webpack config doesn't have much benefit as only the index will actually require ones and rest of the site will be bundled in with the index bundle.  Webpack 2 offers some [code-splitting features](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/) which can help reduce bundle size and which parts get loaded when, but it is all handled by webpack and the bundle, so you don't have to worry about it when linking the bundles to the html.