# How can I add new html files to react application?

Tags: reactjs

I've been searching on internet for this problem and all I am getting is there is no need to create other pages because react is meant for single page application
or solutions that change the content of the page but not the page (url) itself.
What I really want to know  is : 
When I create an app with create-react-app , I get all the setup , now can I create
a new html file like the default index.html is created in public directory and 
render components to that new file ?

Comment: You sure can. All you need to do is call `ReactDOM.render` with the root element you want your React app or component to be attached to on that page, but if you want a single page app you might want to look at `react-router` or `reach-router`

Comment: @WilomGfx if I try it on another page but index it doesn't detect or can't find element with the given id

Comment: `Can't find element with the given id`, this is becuase we have setting in `webpack.config` file for `index.html`. If You want to change the file, you must add that file in `webpack.config` file and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

What CRA is doing is using webpack to bundle your code starting from (default) `src/index.js` file. It means that it creates one (or multiple if lazy loaded) bundles, that are loaded into `public/index.html` file. You can check it by viewing `build/index.html` and looking for scripts loaded before the `</body>` tag.

The main entry point for React is

```js
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

You can have multiple entry points in one HTML file. If you want to have multiple entry points split across multiple files - I am afraid you will need to `eject` your CRA app and tweak webpack config by yourself.

I think similar problem was described here:
[Multiple modules for multiple entry points in webpack config for reactjs app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44156492/multiple-modules-for-multiple-entry-points-in-webpack-config-for-reactjs-app)

But maybe you are just looking for [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start)? You can also adjust your server config to redirect all paths to `index.html` and let react-router handle displaying proper component. E.g. [How to setup apache server for React route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44038456/how-to-setup-apache-server-for-react-route)

Comment: so there is no way doing that with create react app ?

Comment: Well, there is stuff like react-app-rewired and customize-cra, but I do not know if they allow for such customisation.

Answer (score -1):

From your question, it's not quite clear for what exact reason you need multiple HTML files, but consider this from the [CRA readME](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#popular-alternatives):

> If you want to do server rendering with React and Node.js, check out Next.js or Razzle. Create React App is agnostic of the backend, and just produces static HTML/JS/CSS bundles.
>
> If your website is mostly static (for example, a portfolio or a blog), consider using Gatsby instead. Unlike Create React App, it pre-renders the website into HTML at the build time.

So I think there is a need to understand not `whether it is possible to do this with CRA?` but `Why do you need it? And maybe there is a tool more suitable for your case than CRA.`

Maybe [next.js](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/), [razzle](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/razzle) or [gatsbyjs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/) will address your issue.